# How to reduce "sort" cost (t-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting, ssms

I have a T-SQL query. Using *Display Estimated Execution Plan* in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I find the last of the `sort` operations to consume 83% of the totalt cost.

The weird thing is that when I remove the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, it only increases the `sort` cost. So my question is: What else can contribute to cost in this link?

**Query**

```
SELECT                                                                  
o.boardordrenr      as 'SenDX Board Run', 
bo.boardordrerunnr  as 'RMED Board Run',                                                       
o.ordrerunnr        as 'Dispensing Run',                                                                             
o.ordreidnr         as 'Board ID', 
o.boardnr           as 'Board No.',
ba.raekkenr         as 'Row',       
ba.arraynr          as 'Array',
s0.sensor           as 'Sensor',
ks.diameter         as 'Cavity Diameter',
ks.kavitet_dybde    as 'Cavity Depth',
ms1.tykkelse        as 'CA Thickness',
ms1.membrane_Stdev  as 'CA Std. Dev.',
s1.void_procent     as 'CA Void Fraction',
s1.skannet_dt       as 'CA Scan Date',
ms2.tykkelse        as 'OM Thickness',
ms2.membrane_Stdev  as 'OM Std. Dev.',
s2.void_procent     as 'OM Void Fraction',
s2.skannet_dt       as 'OM Scan Date',
ft_sc_par.vaerdi    as 'Sens'


FROM 
boardordre bo                                                                        
INNER JOIN ordre o          ON bo.boardordrenr = o.boardordrenr AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, o.oprettet_dt, GETDATE()) < 3 AND o.ordrevarenr = 932029                                                 
INNER JOIN boardarray ba    ON ba.ordrenr = o.ordrenr    
LEFT JOIN sensorkassette sc ON sc.boardarraynr_bund = ba.boardarraynr

LEFT JOIN skanning s0           ON s0.boardarraynr = ba.boardarraynr AND s0.overflade_index = 0 AND s0.sensor in ('Glu','Lac')  -- Cavity
LEFT JOIN skanning s1           ON s1.boardarraynr = ba.boardarraynr AND s1.overflade_index = 1 AND s1.sensor = s0.sensor       -- CA Membrane
LEFT JOIN skanning s2           ON s2.boardarraynr = ba.boardarraynr AND s2.overflade_index = 2 AND s2.sensor = s0.sensor       -- Outer Membrane

LEFT JOIN kavitetskanning ks    ON ks.skanningnr  = s0.skanningnr    
LEFT JOIN membranskanning ms1   ON ms1.skanningnr = s1.skanningnr  
LEFT JOIN membranskanning ms2   ON ms2.skanningnr = s2.skanningnr AND (ms2.membrannavn = 'YM_UDV' OR ms2.membrannavn = 'YM')

LEFT JOIN funktionstest_sc ft_sc            ON ft_sc.sensorkassette_chipnr = sc.sensorkassette_chipnr
LEFT JOIN funktionstest_sc_param ft_sc_par  ON ft_sc_par.funktionstest_sc_nr = ft_sc.funktionstest_sc_nr AND ft_sc_par.sensor = s0.sensor AND ft_sc_par.parameter = 'Sens'
```

**Execution Plan (Link)**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5957600/sql_execution_plan_actual.sqlplan

Comment: Why are you fixed on improving the sort? Post the actual execution plan so that we can optimize the query as a whole.

Comment: Well, are those columns you're sorting on **indexed**?

Comment: They are not all indexed, thats why I thought removing them might help. It does not... Regarding the execution plan, it is rather large, but I will see I can find some way to upload it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the cost of the query is always 100%. Make sure you _really_ have a problem before you optimize.

Comment: The query takes somewhere from 25-40 seconds to execute, so I would think there is room for optimization. Thats what got me started in the first place.

Comment: distinct can contribute the lot of cost.

Comment: Look for "fat pipes" in the query plan - these indicate large intermediate results that could be the source of the work. Also - might get more clues looking at the actual query plan rather than the estimated plan. It is sometimes pretty different.

Comment: The last couple of pipes contains Esitmated no. of rows: 705,680,000 Estimated data size: 87 GB Estimated row size 132 B

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that some of the joined tables not having a primary key?

Comment: Listen, all of this commentary is pure guessing and waste of time. People just point to their favorite witch in the query. Post the actual plan and as much info about the data as possible. What's your perf goal?

Comment: Yes lack of indexes on join is a problem.   And the so in the where turns the left join into a regular join.

Comment: I added a link to the execution plan, as well as updated the query (the `WHERE` was removed).

Comment: @Noceo no major red flags in that execution plan. You can index parts of it away, you can used indexed views to remove joins entirely. What SQL Server version is this? Is this Enterprise Edition? On 2012+ there is a trick to turn on columnstore batch mode without using any CS index at all... That can help with such queries.

Comment: Server version is 10.50.4321.0, Standard Edition. I've indexed almost all `JOIN` parameters, with little to no effect. I was just wondering if the huge mismatch between estimated number of rows and actual number of rows, could have any influence on performance...?

Answer (score 1):

You did a distinct, to do the distinct efficiently SQL Server probably needs to do a sort first. Your execution plan will give you the answers you need to know. Indexes will definitely help in this case.

Comment: You might be on to something. Removing `DISTINCT` switched the cost from being on `Sort` to being on `Parallelism`. The total execution time did not change however.

Answer (score 1):

put index on all join conditions

s0.sensor in ('Glu','Lac') turned that into an inner join

try this

```
FROM 
    boardordre bo 
INNER JOIN 
    ordre o ON bo.boardordrenr = o.boardordrenr 
            AND o.ordrevarenr = 932029  
            AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, o.oprettet_dt, GETDATE()) < 3 
INNER JOIN 
    boardarray ba ON ba.ordrenr = o.ordrenr    
LEFT JOIN 
    sensorkassette sc ON sc.boardarraynr_bund = ba.boardarraynr
INNER JOIN 
    skanning s0 ON s0.boardarraynr = ba.boardarraynr 
                AND s0.overflade_index = 0 -- Cavity 
                AND s0.sensor in ('Glu','Lac')
```

drop the where

Comment: Getting rid of the `WHERE` roughly halved the run-time of the query. Thanks for the advice. I was under the impression that it didn't matter if conditions were used in `JOIN` or in the end, using `WHERE`